# HTML boxes on left and right sides while having box on center

Tags: html, css, grid

Hi i am having trouble to code html on something like on the picture below. I have tried float left right

but none of these works for the boxes on the left side and right. for the center box i used margin auto left right.
which works fine. Only problem is whenever i try with boxes on left and right side, it results in weird way and I could not figure it out how it should be done. Help appreciated.

[image]
here is the code i have tried and as you might already see i am very new to html.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>page4</title>

<style>

#container
{
    width:1200px;
    height:700px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:grey;
}

#image1
{
    background-color: red;

    height:140px;
    width:300px;

    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#image2
{
    background-color: orange;


    height:140px;
    width:300px;
    float: left;;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#image3
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height:140px;
    width:300px;
float: left;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#image4
{
    background-color: blue;
    height:140px;
    width:300px;

    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#image5
{
    background-color: green;
    height:140px;
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#image6
{
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height:140px;
    width:300px;
    float: right;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#image7
{
    background-color: purple;
    height:140px;
    width:300px;
    float: left;;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#image8
{
    background-color: maroon;
    height:140px;
    width:300px;
    float: left;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:140px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
#footer
{
    background-color: lime;
    height:140px;
    width:1200px;
    float:right;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
}

#content
{
    background-color: pink;

    height:560px;
    width:600px;

    font-size:40px;
    line-height:290px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
        float:left;
}
</style>


</head>



<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="image1"> image1 </div>
<div id="image5"> image5 </div>
<div id="content"> Content</div>

<div id="image6"> image6 </div>
<div id="image7"> image7 </div>
<div id="image8"> image8 </div>

<div id="image2"> image2 </div>



<div id="image3"> image3 </div>
<div id="image4"> image4 </div>















<div id="footer"> footer </div>



</div>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Also, why would you want each one of those boxes to be an image? If the whole layout is images, why not use one image? Not sure if this is what you're attempting, but it's **highly discouraged** to place content in images for accessibility reasons.

Comment: use css's flexbox and this is done with ease, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: We need to see your HTML and CSS code in order to find the error(s). Help us help you.

Comment: i have pasted my code with the question. and i am new to the html and this is one of the problem i am trying to code from one of the website which i am not able to find a solution.

Comment: @Greensky are you going to only place images (`<img>`) in the image DIVs? Also, do you need to use floats or can you use a more modern approach to content layout like `flexbox` or `grid`?

Answer (score -1):

Use css left 0 and right 0 will move your button or div to left and right and even it will be responsive

Comment: There's so much context missing with your suggestion of using `left` and `right`. In most instances, `left` and `right` would not be responsive if something like `position: absolute;` was used. Again, so much context is missing (from OP and this answer).